# How can i install ReportViewer 2012 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

I was using reportviewer 2010 control in visual studio 2010 but i need to start using reportviewer 2012. How can I use the new ASP.NET webforms [ReportViewer 2012 control](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747) in Visual Studio 2010 (without moving up to visual studio 2012)? Eventually I want to move up to Visual Studio 2012 and dotnet 4.5 but I'd prefer to keep using dotnet 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 for a little while longer.

Comment: What is about using Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 in Visual Studio 2010? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442

Comment: I'm already using reportviewer 2010 - i wanted to upgrade to  reportviewer 2012 but i don't see where you can do that and still keeping using asp.net 4.0 and visual studio 2010

Comment: Is there any solution to this? Im trying to install SSRS ReportViewer 2012 on VS2010 - and having similar troubles

Comment: i never found a workaround - have to upgrade to vs 2012 eventually and will get this working then

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how you can 'create reports' for SSRS by the sounds of it, not just display them.  Okay so this will sound weird but you need SQL Server 2012 either Enterprise, Developer, Standard with Advanced Tools edition.  Any one of those should suffice to get you the tool you need.  If you are looking to 'design' reports the tool is an add on to Visual Studio called 'Business Intelligence Development Studio', BIDS for short.  For some reason it shows up now as 'SQL Server Data Tools' under 'All Programs' on Windows.  You can thank Microsoft for making this version as confusing as possible to people looking to get into SSRS.

To install it you simply install all of SQL Server and when you get to the 'Features' section ensure that BIDS is selected.  The version of BIDS IS NOT ON VS 2012, it is on VS 2010.  For some reason the SQL team did not make the deployment of SQL Server coincide with Visual Studio so it goes along with VS 2010, NOT 2012.  A great many people get this confused but I can say for a fact SSRS is an extension of BIDS, which in turn is an extension of Visual Studio.  Not the other way around.  You can create localized reports in VS 2012 that are 'rdlc' files but not the full blown SSRS you deploy to a server there.

Comment: revised my question - actually i'm familiar with using reports in visual studio 2010 with the reportviewer 2010 that comes with visual studio 2010. i was looking for how to install and use report viewer 2012 in the older visual studio 2012 if that is even possible. I know that you could use reportviewer2010 in visual studio 2008 so was hoping they let us do the same thing of using reportviewer 2012 in the older visual studio 2010. i could not find any posts or info on the net about it so that's why i was asking.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 is meant for VS 2010, are you concerned of not having the VS version?  SQL Server's advanced tools installs the studio and the viewer together in a shell, even if you do not have the VS version.  To my knowledge VS 2012 has .net 4.5 and the ability to create, build and use RDLC files only (report CLIENT ONLY files).  As far as I am aware the full fledged SSRS, rdl files, for 2012 only work on VS 2010 unless something has changed in the past few months.

Comment: my target is creating locally processed reports - so with visual studio 2010 you can create a new report and the design tools are all there registered in visual studio 2010 by default. I've heard that you could do the same in visual studio 2008 (but I haven't tried it myself). I was wondering if you could install the reportviewer 2012 in visual studio 2010 or do you have to be using visual studio 2012 to design ssrs reports locally? Guessing that visual studio still lets you work work dotnet 4.0 projects so i can keep to asp.net 4.0 and start using reportviewer 2012 instead.